# Multiple field MongoDB update doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update a couple of fields at once (location and email) but doesn't work:

```
db.collection('userlist').update(
       { username:req.body.username},
       {
          location:req.body.location,
          email:req.body.email
       },
       { upsert: false }, 
       function(err, success) {
          if(err)
            console.log(err);
          else
            console.log(success);
       }
    );
```

For some reason, if I only include one field in this, then it works

```
db.collection('userlist').update(
   { username:req.body.username},
   {
      location:req.body.location
   },
   { upsert: false }, 
   function(err, success) {
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      else
        console.log(success);
   }
);
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? You don't show us here. Your document that you are trying to update would give us a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to update certain fields of an existing doc you need to use [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) or the matching doc will be replaced with your update object (except for `_id`).

So do something like this instead:

```js
db.collection('userlist').update(
   { username:req.body.username},
   { $set: {
      location:req.body.location,
      email:req.body.email
   }},
   { upsert: false }, 
   function(err, success) {
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      else
        console.log(success);
   }
);
```